# Android, Change progress dialog background color?

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have a progress dialog fully defined by java code. I just want to change the background color and probably text color. I've seen other posts in stackoverflow like adding style.xml and so on, but none worked. Please don't refer me to other posts. What to do?
My code sounds like this:

```
 Class A extends Activity {
   ProgressDialog pd;
   Context context;
   public void onCreate(){
   context = A.this;
   pd = new ProgressDialog.show(context, "" , "Loading");
   }
 }
```

[![A sample of progress dialog which i want. Actually i have it
, but the problem is the background color which i want to be white.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Un8B.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Un8B.jpg)

Comment: Is the default color white?

Comment: No, it's black. Actually i want to change it to white.

Comment: Did you use the item `android:alertDialogStyle` in your style.xml?

Comment: read the comment i left for Eric B. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
pd = new ProgressDialog.show(context, "" , "Loading");
pd.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.RED));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your code:

```
Class A extends Activity {
   ProgressDialog pd;
   Context context;
   public void onCreate(){
   context = A.this;
   pd = new ProgressDialog(context, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_Dialog_Alert);
   pd.setTitle("");
   pd.setMessage("Loading");
   pd.show();
   }
 }
```

Comment: I've used style.xml before and managed to change the pd but the result was not what i expected. i just need a simple white pd with a circle spinning inside. Just like Instagram app when scrolling down a list of followers or media or ... . Every style.xml needs a parent theme which won't meet my case.

Comment: _"result was not what i expected"_ how was the pd when you did that? Can you please post the images from instagram so that I'd get an idea.

Comment: I uploaded a screen shot of what i want.

Comment: Well this is not a progress dialog.  This is more of a progress bar, an indeterminate one. You could just control it's visibility, make it gone or visible whatever you want.